# A-Frame Texture not Transparent

Tags: blender, aframe

In my A-Frame scene I have two separate inverted spheres models with two different materials

To create the inverted sphere objects, I am using Blender. I am applying the textures in the texture menu, then applying them as materials. Then, I export the models as .dae with materials included in the export settings.

Textures window for invertedsphere2:

[image]

Materials window for invertedsphere2:

[image]

In this photo, "models/invertedsphere.dae" properly shows "glyphs.png" as the texture.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atyma.jpg]

Here's how my second inverted sphere appears in Blender, and how I assume it should look in A-Frame.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bfck.png]

However, this is how it appears in A-Frame.

[image: non-transparent tex]

The first sphere is 5 units large in every dimension, and the second sphere is 4.7 units large in every dimension, meaning that I should be able to see the first sphere through the transparent areas of the second sphere, however this is not occurring.

How do I get the texture to show properly?

Additionally, my scene code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Aetheria</title>
<meta name="description" content="Aetheria" />
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <!-- Primitives. -->
  <a-box position="-1 0.6 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.35 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.85 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0.1 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-entity collada-model="model/invertedsphere/invertedsphere.dae" scale="5 5 5" position="0 1.441 -2.752"></a-entity>
  <a-entity collada-model="model/invertedsphere/invertedsphere2.dae" scale="4.7 4.7 4.7" position="0 1.441 -2.752"></a-entity>


  <!-- Background sky. -->
  <a-sky height="2048" radius="30" src="#skyTexture" theta-length="90" width="2048"></a-sky>

  <!-- Ground. -->



</a-scene>
```

Comment: did You try to export it as a glTF ?

Comment: Aftet fixing the image tags...  4me it looks as if the rendering hits a depth-limit. For calculation optimization reasons any points wiht distance > SomeValue are not considered - just a hunch though - you might want to search the api. Retracted the close vote. Luck with solving it :)

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I attempted exporting as glTF and the texture isn't appearing at all on the model. Additionally, on my LiveReload server, it appears that the texture is no longer being accessed when the page is reloaded.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you for the help with the image tags, and I apologize if I came off snarky.

Comment: You werent snarky, I was overfast condamming you to blender.stackexchange.com ;) - _most_ blender questions are better suited to be handled there

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I would actually like to avoid gltf for the time being, if possible, because of the fact that it only supports textures added via the node editor. If it's the only possibility, I will stop being lazy and learn the node editor, but otherwise I am looking for a different method that supports transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up finding involved using glTF and the process was much more complicated than I initially anticipated. I will do my best to write a condensed guide here.

1. Clone the [glTF Blender Exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter)
2. Make sure to place the scripts in your Blender add-ons directory and enable it.
3. In the model you wish to texture/add material to, choose "File > Link" then navigate to "(working directory)/glTF-Blender-Exporter/pbr_node/glTF2.blend/Node Tree/" then select either "glTF Metallic Roughness" and/or "glTF Specular Glossiness"
4. Open the [node editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/introduction.html) and make sure that you are displaying Shader Nodes and are taking the Shader Nodes from the object, e.g. [image: node editor settings]
5. In the node editor menu, select "Add > Group > glTF Metallic Roughness/glTF Specular Glossiness", then click anywhere in the node editor to place it.
6. For reference, my object is set up as so: [image: my node tree] 
   Note that my Image Texture's Alpha Channel node connects to the Alpha Channel in the shader. This is the key part that makes the texture transparent.

NOTE: No other shaders will work besides glTF shaders at this time if exporting to glTF.

7. Export as either .glTF or .glb. If you export as .glTF, a .glTF file and a .bin file will be created. The .bin file will contain the material and texture. If you export as a .glb file, the material and texture will be self-contained within the same file as your model.
8. Test using [the glTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). I prefer it to testing in A-Frame because it gives you error output in a clear, readable fashion, and allows you to drag-and-drop models.